# Can't use the camera after turning off the flashlight

Tags: android, camera, flashlight

I'm writing an application for school and it has features that requires the camera to take pictures, crop them, upload them to a server and afterwards the user has to be able to turn on the flashlight (as part of some tracking we're doing).
All the above works perfectly - Untill the user turns off the flashlight and wants to take another picture. The camera stops working shows an error on screen that it can't connect to the camera.

I know there are commands like reconnect: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#reconnect()
I've been fiddling around with it, and I can't for the life of me get it to work.

For using the camera I'm using an intent:

```
Intent intent    = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

And the flashlight code looks like this:

```
private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();

            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

 /*
 * Turning On flash
 */
private void turnOnFlash() {
    getCamera();
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();

        isFlashOn = true;
    }

}

/*
 * Turning Off flash
 */
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        isFlashOn = false;
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can use the same instance of the camera for both the flashlight and the camera (when it's an intent)? I found that if I release the camera et becomes null and it's unable to instanciate it again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try my following answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Decoid You just have to add an on pause method, which i am guessing you haven't
as below:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (!isFlashOn) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

release the camera object on pause, make sure you read android documentation first

[Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html)!

also do read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839000/why-camera-needs-to-be-released-in-onpause-rather-than-onstop-method-of-acti)!