# Why are my SharedPreferences persisting across activites after using clear() in Android?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I've looked all over and can't seem to find an answer to my issue.  For some reason the data saved in `SharedPreferences` reappears after switching activities.  Why is my SharedPreferences still the exact same as it was before I cleared it and how can I fix this?

In first activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(TEMP_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String objectJson = gson.toJson(object, Object.class);
    String activityJson = "FirstActivity";

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString(CONTINUE_KEY, objectJson);
    editor.putString(ACTIVITY_KEY, activityJson);
    editor.apply();
}

public void onClickSave() {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String objectJson = gson.toJson(object);
    SharedPreferences sp getSharedPreferences(SAVE_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString(object.getDate(), objectJson);
    editor.apply();

    SharedPreferences spTemp = this.getSharedPreferences(TEMP_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    spTemp.edit().clear().apply();
    // go back to the main menu
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Before the apply():

[image: Debugger]

After the apply():

[image: Debugger]

**In Main Activity:**

```
SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(TEMP_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

From main activity:

[image: Debugger]

Comment: show `getSharedPreferences()` code

Comment: from which activity? my main activity?

Comment: From both if you for some reason have two implementations

Comment: Is `KEY` the same in both cases?

Comment: I may have just realized what the problem is.  Is my onStop() being called whenever my MainActivity gets called?

Comment: where do you call `SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(TEMP_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);` in MainActivity?

Comment: @Tommy I guess I should have been more clear with that. I call it from a button click function `onClickContinue()`

Comment: @JohnR. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Coordinating activities](http://%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#soafa) android documentation.

> When one activity starts another, they both experience lifecycle
>   transitions. The first activity stops operating and enters the Paused
>   or Stopped state, while the other activity is created. In case these
>   activities share data saved to disc or elsewhere, it's important to
>   understand that the first activity is not completely stopped before
>   the second one is created. Rather, the process of starting the second
>   one overlaps with the process of stopping the first one.
>
> The order of lifecycle callbacks is well defined, particularly when
>   the two activities are in the same process (app) and one is starting
>   the other. Here's the order of operations that occur when Activity A
>   starts Activity B:
>
> 1. Activity A's **onPause()** method executes.
> 2. Activity B's **onCreate()**, **onStart()**, and **onResume()** methods execute in sequence. (Activity B now has user focus.)
> 3. Then, if Activity A is no longer visible on screen, its **onStop()** method executes.
>
> This predictable sequence of lifecycle callbacks allows you to manage
>   the transition of information from one activity to another.

Back to your case, when you start `MainActivity` from `FirstActivity`.

1. `FirstActivity`'s **onPause()** method executes.
2. `MainActivity`'s **onCreate()**, **onStart()**, and **onResume()** methods execute in sequence. (`MainActivity` now has user focus.)
3. Then, if `FirstActivity` is no longer visible on screen, its **onStop()** method executes.

When the code in `onClickSave` executes.

```
SharedPreferences spTemp = this.getSharedPreferences(TEMP_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
spTemp.edit().clear().apply();
```

At this time, `TEMP_KEY` prefs has been cleared. After `MainActivity` is visible on screen, `FirstActivity` will be no longer visible on screen, so its **onStop()** method executes.

```
SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(TEMP_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
Gson gson = new Gson();

String objectJson = gson.toJson(object, Object.class);
String activityJson = "FirstActivity";

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString(CONTINUE_KEY, objectJson);
editor.putString(ACTIVITY_KEY, activityJson);
editor.apply();
```

In this code you add two entries into `TEMP_KEY` prefs again. So when users click on a button in `MainActivity`, at that time the prefs size is 2 instead of 0 as you expected.

> Why is my SharedPreferences still the exact same as it was before I
>   cleared it?

This is predictable or expected behavior in Android. You can put a log in **onCreate()**, **onStart()**, **onResume()** method of `MainActivity`, then you can see `TEMP_KEY` prefs size at that time is always 0.

> How can I fix this?

Do not add new entries into `TEMP_KEY` in **onStop()**, you should add in **onPause()** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Save To Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("test" , MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = sp.edit();
spEditor.putString("hello1" , "hello11");
spEditor.putString("hello2" , "hello22");
spEditor.apply();
```

Clear From Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences sp1 = getSharedPreferences("test" , MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor1 = sp1.edit();
spEditor1.clear();
spEditor1.apply();
```

Get From Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences sp2 = getSharedPreferences("test" , MODE_PRIVATE);
String value =  sp2.getString("hello1" ,"noting");
Log.i("test_sp" , " == == ==" +value);
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you have different preference file name for [getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)), in `onStop()` and `onClickSave()` methods:

```
// in onStop()
SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(TEMP_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);

// in onClickSave()
SharedPreferences sp getSharedPreferences(SAVE_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

you need to use the same file name to access the same preference.

**Second**, `onStop()` is not always guaranteed to be called, so it's not a reliable method to save your preferences. Related answer: [Is onStop() always preceded by onPause()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793194/is-onstop-always-preceded-by-onpause)

**Third**, always save the preference when you need to keep the value in it. Don't wait to save it later and hoping that you can depend on either `onPause()`, `onStop()`, or `onDestroy()`. Never assume that your application will gracely terminate by user or system.

Comment: what's a better way to automatically save if `onPause()` and `onStop()` aren't always reliable?

Comment: No, only `onStop()` isnt' always guaranteed to be called. `onPause()` is guaranteed to be called. Please see this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793194/is-onstop-always-preceded-by-onpause